# Game ideas that you cannot get better at (non electronic)

Tags: board-game-geek

Trying to find a game (non electronic) that requires you to do only one task and that you cannot get better at no matter how much you play. Game at which beginner and pro would have almost equal chances.

Example that would work: You randomly get 10 letters and you need to build a word with them.

Example that would not work: Riddles (as at some point of time you will know the answers to many of them) which meant you will be better than the person that never played before.

Comment: If it requires skill, an experienced player will have an advantage over a weak one. If it doesn't require skill, it's not a game. Also, game recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Your example that would work is basically scrabble and the more you play the better you can be.

Comment: The card game war, where you split the deck and flip the top card to see who wins. I remember really enjoying it as a kid, but there is no way to be 'good' at the game. Just a coin flip simulator.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the only cases that really work are:

1. Solved games (e.g. Tic-Tac-Toe, where any player beyond a certain skill point is able to force a draw)
2. Games requiring no skill at all (e.g. Candyland, where your moves are determined entirely by a card draw)

Things like "Make a word out of these letters" depend on how big your vocabulary is, and "Make these numbers equal this other number" depend on your mathematical acuity - see the UK show "Countdown" (or its Australian equivalent "Letters and Numbers"), so that unless everyone has unlimited time and resources, there is still a gap between a beginner and a pro.

Puzzles like Sudoku are similar - technically, anyone could solve any sudoku if given enough time and support, and indeed people could apply different skills to solve the same puzzle (I could, for example, write a computer program to solve a sudoku, which might take me about the same amount of time as it takes you to brute force the solution).